# EXtJS grid CheckColumn, How to execute function, after column is clicked/its state is checked?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have ExtJS GRID with checkcolumn, which is declared this way:

```
// the check column is created using a custom plugin
sel_column = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
   sortable: false,
   header: 'STE<br />SEL',
   dataIndex: 'sel',
   width: field_w,

    listeners:
    {

      "mousedown":
      {
        fn : function(e)
        {    
            $.log( "Sel cellclick" , e );
        }
      }    

    }


});
```

I want add some listener on changfe of it stae, or on mouse click. 
Finaly - want id's of rows, where i click this column - to be stored in text field

For now i can understood how to catch click event, i use onMouseDown, this way:

```
// the check column is created using a custom plugin
sel_column = new Ext.grid.CheckColumn({
   sortable: false,
   header: 'STE<br />SEL',
   dataIndex: 'sel',
   width: field_w,

   onMouseDown: function( e )
   {
     $.log( e,"MouseDown" );
   }


});
```

But it fires, when i click ANY cell, not only checkboxed ...

Pls help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

checkbox plugin need modification, after which it can fire click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
**************************************************************
Sample to add event 'checkchange' in checkbox on checkcolumn,
works with ExtJS 4 or above
*/
//Add you checkcolumn   id:'op_check'. No need separate plugin.
//Put this code in You Grid

listeners:{
    afterrender:function(){
        g = this;   //This grid
        Ext.getCmp('op_check').on('checkchange', function(c, i){
            //Get id from row/record (if in store exist field 'id')
            //"i" - in this function is index row, where clicked checkbox
            rec = g.store.getAt(i);
            id = rec.get('id');
            console.log(id); //:)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: And how got id of row/record, where is this checkbox?